# Ubuntu One state still processing, Process Sleeping, not transfer uploads/downloads

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, files

Greetings Ubuntu One Support,

I install ubuntu 11.04 x86 and I have a 100MB Interent connection.

I payed for addtional 20GB pack for backup my photos, and I select my whole "~/Pictures" folder for sync... but the daemon never upload the files...

```
user@user-lap:~$ u1sdtool -s
State: QUEUE_MANAGER
    connection: With User With Network
    description: processing the commands pool
    is_connected: True
    is_error: False
    is_online: True
    queues: WORKING

user@user-lap:~$ u1sdtool --current-transfers
Current uploads: 0
Current downloads: 0
```

Using "magicicada" I can see all the 7,470 files queued with the operaiton "Upload"... but nothing happen! I check in the one.ubuntu.com/files/ and there is the empty folders. I was waiting for more than 2hrs and nothing get transferd

Everytime that I restart my laptop, Ubuntu One upload just 1 file... I can't restart my computer 7,470 times for transfer all my data.

I check the Ubuntu One Status in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status ... and there says that the File service is working...

There is a very long log about it at `./cache/ubuntuone/log/syncdaemon.log`, but it just repeats something like:

```
2011-09-20 11:19:14,479 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.InteractionInterfaces - DEBUG - called current_status
2011-09-20 11:19:14,481 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.DBus - DEBUG - called current_uploads
```

I noticed that when was uploaded 100% of a large file (video) remains in that status and never disappears from the queue in the ubuntuone-Indicator ... I do not see the file in the web-interface one.ubuntu.com

What happen? This service really doesn't work?

Comment: You can see the file syncdaemon.log into the folder ./cache/ubuntuone/log/ check if some file is causing a problem.